# ffmpeg error opening filters at mobile browser

Tags: android, ios, ffmpeg, frontend

I use the ffmpeg at mobile browser. But it responds `Error opening filter` both at safari and chrome. I need help. The log are as following.

The IOS 11.0.2 Safari logs:

```
[Log] ffmpeg version n3.1.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers (bundle.js, line 43469)
  built with emcc (Emscripten gcc/clang-like replacement) 1.36.7 ()
  configuration: --cc=emcc --enable-cross-compile --target-os=none --arch=x86 --disable-runtime-cpudetect --disable-asm --disable-fast-unaligned --disable-pthreads --disable-w32threads --disable-os2threads --disable-debug --disable-stripping --disable-all --enable-ffmpeg --enable-avcodec --enable-avformat --enable-avutil --enable-swresample --enable-swscale --enable-avfilter --disable-network --disable-d3d11va --disable-dxva2 --disable-vaapi --disable-vda --disable-vdpau --enable-decoder=vp8 --enable-decoder=vp9 --enable-decoder=theora --enable-decoder=mpeg2video --enable-decoder=mpeg4 --enable-decoder=h264 --enable-decoder=hevc --enable-decoder=png --enable-decoder=mjpeg --enable-decoder=vorbis --enable-decoder=opus --enable-decoder=mp3 --enable-decoder=ac3 --enable-decoder=aac --enable-decoder=ass --enable-decoder=ssa --enable-decoder=srt --enable-decoder=webvtt --enable-demuxer=matroska --enable-demuxer=ogg --enable-demuxer=avi --enable-demuxer=mov --enable-demuxer=flv --enable-demuxer=mpegps --enable-demuxer=image2 --enable-demuxer=mp3 --enable-demuxer=concat --enable-protocol=file --enable-filter=aresample --enable-filter=scale --enable-filter=crop --enable-filter=overlay --disable-bzlib --disable-iconv --disable-libxcb --disable-lzma --disable-sdl --disable-securetransport --disable-xlib --disable-zlib --enable-encoder=libx264 --enable-encoder=libmp3lame --enable-encoder=aac --enable-muxer=mp4 --enable-muxer=mp3 --enable-muxer=null --enable-gpl --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libx264 --extra-cflags=-I../lame/dist/include --extra-ldflags=-L../lame/dist/lib
  libavutil      55. 28.100 / 55. 28.100
  libavcodec     57. 48.101 / 57. 48.101
  libavformat    57. 41.100 / 57. 41.100
  libavfilter     6. 47.100 /  6. 47.100
  libswscale      4.  1.100 /  4.  1.100
  libswresample   2.  1.100 /  2.  1.100
[h264 @ 0x809df0] Warning: not compiled with thread support, using thread emulation
[aac @ 0x80e380] Warning: not compiled with thread support, using thread emulation
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '53119917068__7A6AFE7C-86EC-42F4-8995-A9B09B16C2DB.MOV':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt  
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: qt  
    creation_time   : 2017-11-01 03:19:31
    com.apple.quicktime.make: Apple
    com.apple.quicktime.model: iPhone 6
    com.apple.quicktime.software: 11.0.2
    com.apple.quicktime.creationdate: 2017-11-01T11:19:31+0800
  Duration: 00:00:00.20, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1467 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, smpte170m/bt709/bt709), 480x360, 1131 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 600 tbn, 1200 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      rotate          : 90
      creation_time   : 2017-11-01 03:19:31
      handler_name    : Core Media Data Handler
      encoder         : H.264
    Side data:
      displaymatrix: rotation of -90.00 degrees
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp, 80 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2017-11-01 03:19:31
      handler_name    : Core Media Data Handler
    Stream #0:2(und): Data: none (mebx / 0x7862656D), 0 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2017-11-01 03:19:31
      handler_name    : Core Media Data Handler
    Stream #0:3(und): Data: none (mebx / 0x7862656D), 0 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2017-11-01 03:19:31
      handler_name    : Core Media Data Handler
Error opening filters!
```

The Android 7.0 Chrome logs:

```
ffmpeg version n3.1.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with emcc (Emscripten gcc/clang-like replacement) 1.36.7 ()
  configuration: --cc=emcc --enable-cross-compile --target-os=none --arch=x86 --disable-runtime-cpudetect --disable-asm --disable-fast-unaligned --disable-pthreads --disable-w32threads --disable-os2threads --disable-debug --disable-stripping --disable-all --enable-ffmpeg --enable-avcodec --enable-avformat --enable-avutil --enable-swresample --enable-swscale --enable-avfilter --disable-network --disable-d3d11va --disable-dxva2 --disable-vaapi --disable-vda --disable-vdpau --enable-decoder=vp8 --enable-decoder=vp9 --enable-decoder=theora --enable-decoder=mpeg2video --enable-decoder=mpeg4 --enable-decoder=h264 --enable-decoder=hevc --enable-decoder=png --enable-decoder=mjpeg --enable-decoder=vorbis --enable-decoder=opus --enable-decoder=mp3 --enable-decoder=ac3 --enable-decoder=aac --enable-decoder=ass --enable-decoder=ssa --enable-decoder=srt --enable-decoder=webvtt --enable-demuxer=matroska --enable-demuxer=ogg --enable-demuxer=avi --enable-demuxer=mov --enable-demuxer=flv --enable-demuxer=mpegps --enable-demuxer=image2 --enable-demuxer=mp3 --enable-demuxer=concat --enable-protocol=file --enable-filter=aresample --enable-filter=scale --enable-filter=crop --enable-filter=overlay --disable-bzlib --disable-iconv --disable-libxcb --disable-lzma --disable-sdl --disable-securetransport --disable-xlib --disable-zlib --enable-encoder=libx264 --enable-encoder=libmp3lame --enable-encoder=aac --enable-muxer=mp4 --enable-muxer=mp3 --enable-muxer=null --enable-gpl --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libx264 --extra-cflags=-I../lame/dist/include --extra-ldflags=-L../lame/dist/lib
  libavutil      55. 28.100 / 55. 28.100
  libavcodec     57. 48.101 / 57. 48.101
  libavformat    57. 41.100 / 57. 41.100
  libavfilter     6. 47.100 /  6. 47.100
  libswscale      4.  1.100 /  4.  1.100
  libswresample   2.  1.100 /  2.  1.100
[hevc @ 0x809db0] Warning: not compiled with thread support, using thread emulation
[aac @ 0x80ea90] Warning: not compiled with thread support, using thread emulation
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'VID_20171101_113436.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: isommp42
    creation_time   : 2017-11-01 03:34:40
    com.android.version: 7.0
  Duration: 00:00:02.69, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 32551 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: hevc (Main) (hvc1 / 0x31637668), yuv420p(tv), 3840x2160, 29756 kb/s, SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9, 29.60 fps, 29.83 tbr, 90k tbn, 90k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      rotate          : 90
      creation_time   : 2017-11-01 03:34:40
      handler_name    : VideoHandle
    Side data:
      displaymatrix: rotation of -90.00 degrees
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 192 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2017-11-01 03:34:40
      handler_name    : SoundHandle
Error opening filters!
```

Comment: Share the full command.

Comment: The parameters are like these: `'-i', 'screenshoot.mp4', '-an', '-r', '15', '-s', '320*240', 'output.webm'`.@Mulvya

Comment: Upgrade ffmpeg and try. The error messages have changed and are more specific.